# Mouse event throttling architecture

Tags: javascript, events, throttling

I have a set of nested DOM elements with mouse event handlers (mouseover, mouseout). Side effects of the events update other views; these updates are potentially computationally expensive, and can create annoying visual flicker, so I would like to minimize them. My first thought was to build a throttling mechanism that delays the handling of a mouse-over event for some interval, giving the mouse a chance to exit the element in question. If no exit occurs within the specified interval, the event is fired; if an exit occurs, the event is canceled without being propagated.

My question is whether existing UI frameworks already support such mechanisms, and, if so, which ones do so? While I can certainly build this, it seems like a problem that others might have solved already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [underscore js' throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) on your mouse event handlers. This was recently blogged about on the toggl blog: http://blog.toggl.com/2013/02/increasing-perceived-performance-with-_throttle/. There was some monkey patching of jQuery involved, though, so it's not the cleanest method.

Comment: this is close, but not exactly my problem: I don't necessarily have lots of redundant events of which I would like to keep a subset; I have some events that may get suppressed entirely if the terminating event happens within a short-enough interval of the initiating event.